# Selenium WebDriver w/Java - Trouble selecting parent/descendent nodes?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I'm using xpath with Java and Selenium WebDriver to select a node from an XML tree on a webpage. I need to select the node which is a hyperlink with class = "red-button" and is a descendent (not direct child) of a div element with a class = "step". This is my code:

```
List<WebElement> goButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/div[@class=\"step\"]/a[@class=\"red-button\"]"));

        if(goButton.get(0)!= null){
            continueButton.get(0).click();
        }
```

I need to wait for the red-button element to appear, as it is loaded dynamically. This is why I chose to use the findElements() method instead of just findElement(). My understanding is that findElements() pools the DOM until it finds the element or times out.  When I run my code I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

which means goButton is null, therefore WebDriver could not find the element.  Am I doing something wrong in my Java logic or do I need to fix the xpath query?

Comment: try this - `List<WebElement> goButton = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.step a.red-button"));`

Comment: Small hint: XPath also allows usage of single quotes for strings, there is no need for escaping double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPATH is incorrect.

`/div` will find a div that is immediately under the root DOM node.  You want `//div` at the beginning, and `//a` to find the link.  Here are some solutions.

Using CSS (which is much cleaner and faster than xpath)..

```
List<WebElement> goButton = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.step a.red-button"));
```

Using XPATH (if you really are persistent about using it.

```
List<WebElement> goButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='step']//a[@class='red-button']"));
```

Since you are looking for a descendent, and NOT a child, you need to use xpath's `//` not `/`